# Installing CocoaPods with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am using the latest XCode IDE and decided to go with CocoaPods now. (I am using swift) so I installed cocoaPods using

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

after that I called pod init, changed the podfile to this

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
pod 'RESideMenu'
pod 'UIImage-Resize'
pod 'UzysAssetsPickerController'
```

And I setup the bridging Header. 
Now I expected that I could use this: UzysAssetsPickerController

But each time I try to Build, I get the error:

```
No such Module UzysAssetsPickerController
```

Is there something that I need to configure If I try to use pods within an existing project and swift?

This is my bridge header:

```
#import <RESideMenu/RESideMenu.h>
#import <UzysAssetsPickerController/UzysAssetsPickerController.h>
```

Comment: Can you paste your bridge header?

Comment: Did you follow step 2 in the installation instructions? [Installation Instructions](https://github.com/uzysjung/UzysAssetsPickerController#installation)

Comment: Did you run `pod install`?

Comment: Make sure in your Build Settings you have "Install Objective-C Compatibility Header" to true, and that Objective-C Bridging Header is set to the path/filename.h

Comment: @Chris no I haven't 
why do I need to copy these files? I thought cocoaPods does this for me?

yeah I have run pod install

Comment: @slik thats on true already.

Comment: @Christian Try and copy those files over as it says, then it should work

Comment: @Chris But this project does the same and obviously doesn't need to copy the files https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao

Comment: It does, if you look [here](https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao/tree/master/AppMessage/AppMessage/Resources)

Comment: Omfg. U are right.. But what do I need pods for then?